# how to get nonce using json api

Tags: api, nonce, plugin-json-api

I try to open this url in my browser or calling from my frontend application: 
    http://78.47.177.214/blog/api/get_nonce/?controller=posts&method=create_post
i keep getting the response

`{"status":"error","error":"Include 'controller' and 'method' vars in your request."}`

what is wrong, I want to be able to create a custom post type with custom fields in the end but using json api I need nonce first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call like below.

**API call:-**

```
http://78.47.177.214/blog/api/get_nonce/?json=get_nonce&controller=posts&method=create_post
```

**Responce:-**

```
{"status":"ok","controller":"posts","method":"create_post","nonce":"92f31d49b5"}
```

Comment: how to create nonce for custom post, say add new book ? I have used ACF and CPT UI to create custom post type 'book'